# How to style React-component's CSS file imported from UI framework

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design

I am evaluating to build quite a big application with React, i am new at React philosophy (I come from Css+Js+jQuery old-school)

One thing I need is a good UI framework implementing Google Material Design. I read lots of stackoverflow threads about people having trouble with React and some MD frameworks.
I figured out that using a classic UI framework, I mean not designed for React, is not a good solution, because such frameworks change the DOM and this could conflict with React event manager and so on. So it seems the right way is to use a UI framework which is made of React components.

I tried some of these (material-ui, react-toolbox, essence, ...) but what is new (and surprising) to me is that I can only change some "theme", let's say "light-theme" or "dark-theme". Or else I can import some themes through a JS import and then call something like

```
$color-primary: $palette-blue-500;
```

to change some colors.
But **this is not enough. I need to have a full editable CSS**, or at least get to know all the CSS class hierarchy and be free to override such classes.

Isn't this possible?
Does this mean that if I need fully-customizable components this is the wrong way to follow?
Or am I missing the "right" library which is giving this opportunity?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the case of `react-toolbox` you can pass in a theme that can fully customize the component, see http://react-toolbox.com/#/install and especially `Customizing components`.

Answer (score 0):

Every React ui framework provides a way to add your own classes and style
using props like className

```
<md-toolbar className="yourclassNames"/>
```

Definitely you can override the top level variables like primary color in a theme . Customizing is highly possible , you just create your own css file and add the required styles.

Sometimes with these libraries you might need use to !important because these libraries do lot on inline styling